# Create a zip archive with Cmake without parent directory?

Tags: cmake

When I do this:

```
add_custom_target(
    mystuff
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "cvf" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mystuff.zip" --format=zip -- ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/stuff/
)
```

against a directory organized like this:

```
stuff/
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
  file3.txt
```

The resulting zip file contains:

```
stuff/
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
  file3.txt
```

but I want: (no parent directory)

```
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
  file3.txt
```

If I were doing this outside of cmake, I would use the `-C` argument (change directory)

How to do this with cmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the working directory of the tar command, something like this:

```
add_custom_target(
    mystuff
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/stuff"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar "cvf" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mystuff.zip" --format=zip .
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the whole thing simpler by removing the nested call to CMake, and calling zip directly:

```
add_custom_target(
    mystuff
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/stuff"
    COMMAND zip -r "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mystuff.zip" . 
)
```

---

(Note: original didn't work, see comment below)
Tell tar to include only the contents of the directory (it will do so recursively, but will leave off the top level).

```
tar "cvf" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mystuff.zip" --format=zip \
    -- ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/stuff/*
```

Comment: However, this wont find files starting with `.`.

Comment: Thanks - it seems like the simplest answer always has a twist in *nix.

Comment: Calling zip does work.  Is there no way to called cmake's tar + zip thing (to avoid the dependency)?

Comment: TBH, it didn't click that the _tar_ you're using is built into CMake.  Clearly, the other answer is what you're looking for.